# JQuery real-time search with Django paginator

Tags: jquery, real-time

I implemented a real-time search for an html table that gets data from a DB. The data is paginated (with Django paginator) so my real-time search only searchs in the first page.

Is there a way of searching in all the pages?

This is my real-time search code:

```
       for(row=1; row<row_length; row++){

             var data=$('#tbody_tabla tr:eq('+row+') td:eq('+column_sel+')').text();

             if(data.indexOf(busqueda) == -1){

                $('#tbody_tabla tr:eq('+row+')').css("display", "none");

             }

           }

           $('#reload').css("visibility", "visible");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to build an REST API to return html table data. Whenever search is invoked, call the API using AJAX call and refresh the result of HTML table on frontend.